# How change format of dateTime json on jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

Now when I show date and time form DB, it's looks like that:

> Tue Dec 12 2017 02:03:00 GMT+0000 (Eastern Daylight Time) 4min. Description:duntik2

And also I need show time and (time + duration). Like that:

> 02:03 - 02:07

I like to see the output like this

> Tue Dec 12 2017 02:03 - 02:07 Description: duntik2

There is my jquery ajax code

```
$.ajax({
  url: url,
  type: 'GET',
    dataType: 'json',
  success: function (data) {
    var ul= $("#list_of_appointments");
    for (i=0; i<data.length; i++){
      var date = new Date(data[i].date_time);
      var li= "<li><span class='date_time'>" + date + " </span>" +
                    "<span class='duration' Duration >" + data[i].duration + "min.</span>" +
                "<span class='description'>" + data[i].description +
            " </span>" + "<input type='hidden' value=" + data[i].id + " /></li>";
      ul.append(li);
    }});
```

So can you help me to change this code?

Comment: look at https://github.com/taylorhakes/fecha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the [`toLocaleDateString`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleDateString) and [`toLocaleTimeString`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleTimeString) methods.

```js
var i = 0, data = [{date_time: new Date(), duration:4, description:'Duntik', id:'some-id'}];
var date = new Date(data[i].date_time),
  enddate = new Date(date);

enddate.setMinutes(enddate.getMinutes() + data[i].duration); // create the enddate from where we will extract the ending time

var formattedDate = date.toLocaleDateString('en-US', {
    weekday: 'short',
    month: 'short',
    day: 'numeric',
    year: 'numeric',
    hour: '2-digit',
    minute: '2-digit',
    hour12: false
  }).replace(/,/g, ''),
  formattedTime = enddate.toLocaleTimeString('en-US', {
    hour: '2-digit',
    minute: '2-digit',
    hour12: false
  });

var li = "<li><span class='date_time'>" + formattedDate + ' - ' + formattedTime + " </span>" +
  "<span class='description'>" + data[i].description +
  " </span>" + "<input type='hidden' value=" + data[i].id + " /></li>";


console.log(li);
```